# Find Acronyms from a sentence in C

Tags: c

[The assignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33L74.jpg)

Below is what I have so far. It's not much and it's probably incorrect so any help is appreciated.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
    char word[1000]; 
    char output[1000];
    int n = 50;
    int i, j;

    printf("Please enter a sentence no larger than 1000 characters: ");
    for(i = 0, i < n, i++)
        scanf("%s", &word[i]);

    int length = strlen(word);
    for(i = 0, i < length, i++) {
        if (length <= 4)
        else
        if(word[i] >= 'A' && word[i] <= 'Z') {
            output[i] = word[i];
        }  
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: why the javascript, c# and c++ tags? Anyway, looks right, does it work right and produce the right results?

Comment: You have `{{scanf` and unnecessary `if (length <= 4)` condition

Comment: Good catch here, the second for loop isn't within the scope of the first, so she is only checking the length of the last word...

Comment: seeing as you originally tagged javascript ... `Array.from(new Set(sentence.split(/[\s,.]+/).filter(i => ['TBH', 'BRB', 'LOL', 'IDK', 'TTYL', 'IRL', 'TIA', 'AFK', 'CYA', 'FYI', 'OMG'].includes(i)))).join('\n')` there you go

Comment: generally we are not here to do your homework. ( I am supprised you get such detailed answers).  You should ask about a specific problem you have. Not what the solution for your assignment is.

Comment: the assignment fails to indicate how duplicate acronyms are to be handled.  I.E. each duplicate listed or only one listing regardless of the number of duplicates

Comment: regarding: `scanf("%s", &word[i]);`  1) always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  2) when using the format specifiers `%s` and/or `%[...]` always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is one less than the length of the input buffer.  Because a) to avoid an possibility of input buffer overflow and b) because those format specifiers always append a NUL byte to the input

Answer (score 2):

It is always a good idea to take hints from the assignment to point you in the direction your instructor intended. In reading through it, `3)` seems like your instructor intended you to use `strtok` and `strcmp` to identify the acronyms given in the assignment (`strcpy` is superfluous unless you want to copy the words to a separate buffer -- not required to produce the `"Output:"` required by the assignment)

You are also to use the `read_line` function to read the `"Input:"`, but since that is something not provided, we will have to assume it will read a line of text `1000` characters or less (including the *nul-terminating* character) into a fixed buffer (as there is no mention of dynamically allocating storage).

You are next given a list of delimiters you are to use to separate the words (tokens) from the line of input. You are told `"white spaces, comma, period and exclamation point"` (which we will presume `"white spaces"` to include `space, tab, newline`, ignoring vertical tab as it is quite uncommon today. You can specify the delimiters in a string to pass to `strtok` as:

```
    const char *delim = " \t\n,.!";
```

(the `const` being somewhat of a formality as a *string literal* declared as `char *foo = "stuff";` is created within the `.rodata` section of the executable and is immutable)

You can also declare the list of acronyms as *string literals* used to initialize an array of pointers to `const char*` (the `const` again a formality as above), e.g.

```
    const char *acronyms[] = { "TBH", "BRB", "LOL", "IDK", "TTYL", "IRL",
                                "TIA", "AFK", "CYA", "FYI", "OMG" };
```

Then to determine the number of acronyms contained in `acronyms[]`, you can divide the `sizeof acronyms` by the `sizeof an_element`, e.g. `sizeof *arcronyms` (or `sizeof acronyms[0]`, your choice), e.g.

```
    size_t n = sizeof acronyms / sizeof *acronyms;  /* number acronyms */
```

You next will need to prompt for input and read the input with `read_line` into a buffer (say `char line[1000] = "";`) of at least `1000` characters. You can then use `strtok` to extract each word (token) from the line, where each word extracted will be separated by one or more of the delimiters contained within the string `delim`. When using `strtok`, your first call uses a reference (a pointer) to the buffer as the first parameter. `strtok` will return a pointer to the extracted word (or NULL if no word is extracted) Here a simple pointer `char *p;` is used to point to the return from `strtok`, e.g.

```
    puts ("Output:");
    p = strtok (line, delim);   /* 1st call to strtok uses line */
```

While `p` is not `NULL`, you can then loop, checking the token pointed to by `p` against each acronym in `acronyms`, e.g.

```
    while (p != NULL) {         /* while p not NULL */
        size_t i;               /* loop variable */
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {   /* loop over each acronym */
            if (strcmp (p, acronyms[i]) == 0) { /* does it match? */
                printf ("%s\n", p); /* print it */
                break;          /* get next word */
            }
        }
        p = strtok (NULL, delim);   /* remaining calls use NULL */
    }
```

(**note:** all calls to `strtok` after the first use `NULL` instead of `line` to extract the remaining tokens.)

That is pretty much a fair reading of what your instructor wanted. There is no need to take the length of any token, nor any compelling reason to limit the number of tokens examined to `500` (as you simply extract tokens to the end of your `1000` character input. At most you could have 500 `I` or `a` separated by a delimiter plus the *nul-terminating* character contained in line. I'll leave it to you whether you want to add that somewhat impossible limit for completion.

Putting the foregoing altogether and inventing a reasonable `read_line`, you could do something similar to the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXC 1000   /*   if you need constants, define them   */
                    /* (don't put magic numbers in your code) */

char *read_line (char *line, size_t max, FILE* fp)
{
    if (fgets (line, max, fp)) {
        size_t len = strlen (line);
        if (len && line[len-1] == '\n')
            line[--len] = 0;
        else
            fprintf (stderr, "warning: characters may remain unread.\n");
        return line;
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main (void)
{
    const char *acronyms[] = { "TBH", "BRB", "LOL", "IDK", "TTYL", "IRL",
                                "TIA", "AFK", "CYA", "FYI", "OMG" },
        *delim = " \t\n,.!";    /* delimiters for strtok */
    char line[MAXC] = "",   /* initialize strings all zero */
        *p = NULL;          /* initialize pointers NULL */
    size_t n = sizeof acronyms / sizeof *acronyms;  /* number acronyms */

    printf ("Input [%d character max]: ", MAXC);    /* prompt */
    if (read_line (line, MAXC, stdin) == NULL) {    /* read/validate line */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    puts ("Output:");
    p = strtok (line, delim);   /* 1st call to strtok uses line */
    while (p != NULL) {         /* while p not NULL */
        size_t i;               /* loop variable */
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {   /* loop over each acronym */
            if (strcmp (p, acronyms[i]) == 0) { /* does it match? */
                printf ("%s\n", p); /* print it */
                break;          /* get next word */
            }
        }
        p = strtok (NULL, delim);   /* remaining calls use NULL */
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
> bin\strtok_acronym.exe
Input [1000 character max]: TBH, IDK if my hashtag will end up trending or if
anyone will even like it. It will only be viral if people can realte to it IRL.
Output:
TBH
IDK
IRL
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions. This isn't the only way to do this -- just the closest that matches the hints your instructor gave. You can loop over the input a character at a time if you like picking out the acronyms as you go. There are may ways to do this.

Answer (score 1):

**first**: acronyms are already given, so keep them in an array.
**second**: read a sentence from user (use custom getline function, it is safe one).
**third**: loop through your acronyms, check if that acronym exists in sentence with `strstr` function. if yes print that acronym, and go to the next acronym.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

char* my_getline()
{
    char * line = malloc(100), * linep = line;
    size_t lenmax = 100, len = lenmax;
    int c;

    if(line == NULL)
        return NULL;

    for(;;) {
        c = fgetc(stdin);
        if(c == EOF)
            break;

        if(--len == 0) {
            len = lenmax;
            char * linen = realloc(linep, lenmax *= 2);

            if(linen == NULL) {
                free(linep);
                return NULL;
            }
            line = linen + (line - linep);
            linep = linen;
        }

        if((*line++ = c) == '\n')
            break;
    }
    *line = '\0';
    return linep;
}

int main()
{
    char *acronymz[] = {"TBH", "BRB", "LOL", "IDK", "TTYL", "IRL", "TIA", "AFK", "CYA", "FYI", "OMG"};
    char *sentence1;

    printf("Please enter a sentence no larger than 1000 characters: ");
    sentence1 = my_getline();

    for(int i=0; i<11; i++) {
        if(strstr(sentence1, acronymz[i]) != NULL) {
            printf("%s\n", acronymz[i]);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A key point to realize here is that there is **no need to keep the entire input in memory**. Only a string up to the longest acronym is required.

Moreover, since the list of acronyms is known in advance, the program is a [DFA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton).

Therefore, there is no need to use `read_line`, `strtok` and related functions.

Note that the assignment is trying to make you accustomed to the C string functions; however, in this case, using them is far from the optimal solution.

An example of how to write this program using a finite amount of memory while keeping the list of acronyms easy-to-change is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ARRAYSIZE(x) (int)(sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0]))
#define LONGEST 5

static int issep(int c)
{
    return c == ' ' || c == '.' || c == ',' || c == '!';
}

int main()
{
    static const char s[][LONGEST] = {
        "TBH",  "BRB",  "LOL",  "IDK", "TTYL", "IRL",
        "TIA",  "AFK",  "CYA",  "FYI", "OMG",
    };

    char sc[ARRAYSIZE(s)];
    char b[LONGEST];
    int word = -1;
    int c = 0;
    int i;

    memset(sc, 0, sizeof(sc));

    for (;;) {
        if (c == '\n')
            break;

        c = getchar();

        if (word == -1) {
            if (issep(c))
                continue;

            if (c == '\n')
                break;

            word = 0;
        }

        if (word >= 0) {
            if (c != '\n' && !issep(c)) {
                if (word >= LONGEST)
                    continue;

                b[word] = c;
                ++word;
                continue;
            }

            if (word >= LONGEST) {
                word = -1;
                continue;
            }

            for (i = 0; i < ARRAYSIZE(s); ++i) {
                if (sc[i])
                    continue;

                if (memcmp(s[i], b, word) == 0)
                    sc[i] = 1;
            }

            word = -1;
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < ARRAYSIZE(s); ++i)
        if (sc[i])
            puts(s[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you read the assignment where the instructor said to use `read_line` for input, and `strtok` and `strcmp` to assist in the code? I agree there is no other buffer needed other than the one the `read_line` takes.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: Yeah, it is the reason why I noted the assignment's intention. There were already other two answers covering that, so it seemed reasonable to cover what the proper solution would be. In any case, the assignment only suggests to use `strtok` etc.  Regarding `read_line`, it is not that clear whether it is required or just suggested (i.e. it is possible that it is a helper function for the students since they may have not covered I/O properly yet, rather than a hard requirement); so it stands to reason that this answer is valid (specially since this is in the context of learning).

Comment: No dings for it. I was just wondering what your thought process was. Like I said, I agree with your assessment of no need for any additional storage, etc.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: Sorry, I didn't mean to sound rude or anything. I agree that your answer is the closest to the actual assignment, so I upvoted it.